# How to use multiple options in apt sources.list?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

Using Ubuntu 22.04. I have added `nodejs` repo [following their official manual](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions). However, when I do `sudo apt update`, I am getting:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I did some research and to fix this, I have to add `[arch=amd64]` option to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`. However, when I open the file, the source already has an option:

```
[signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg]
```

How to use multiple options values in `apt`'s `sources.list`?

I have tried separating them with `,` (comma),  but this doesn't work:

```
deb [arch=amd64,signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro main
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two formats that allow you to add multiple options to `apt` sources: the one-line style format, which uses `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and the DEB822 style format, which uses `.sources` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. The one-line style format is currently used, but the DEB822 style format is planned to gradually become the default. The usage of each format is described below.

---

### `.list` - One-line style format

According to the [`sources.list(5)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/sources.list.5.en.html) the options have to be **separated with spaces** when using the one-line style format:

> If options should be provided they are separated by spaces and all of them together are enclosed by square brackets ([]) included in the line after the type separated from it with a space. If an option allows multiple values these are separated from each other with a comma (,). An option name is separated from its value(s) by an equals sign (=). Multivalue options also have -= and += as separators, which instead of replacing the default with the given value(s) modify the default value(s) to remove or include the given values.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` should look like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro main
```

---

### `.sources` - DEB822 style format

According to the [`sources.list(5)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/sources.list.5.en.html), if you are using the DEB822 format, options are set the same way as the the other fields.

> Options have the same syntax as every other field: A field name
> separated by a colon (:) and optionally spaces from its value(s). Note
> especially that multiple values are separated by whitespaces (like
> spaces, tabs and newlines), not by commas as in the one-line format.
> Multivalue fields like Architectures also have Architectures-Add and
> Architectures-Remove to modify the default value rather than replacing
> it.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.sources` should look like this:

```
Enabled: yes
Types: deb
URIs: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x
Suites: nodistro
Components: main
Architectures: amd64
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
```

---

**Related:**

- [Explanation of the DEB822 Source Format](https://repolib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deb822-format.html)