# Problems installing MS SQL Server and MySQL on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mysql, sql, mssql

I wanted to download and install the SQL server and MySQL to execute my queries in Ubuntu Linux 22.04. I faced many problems but now I was stuck in the major issue. When I run
`dpkg -l | grep -i mysql`
it shows various SQL server named as `mysql-server`, `mysql-community`, `mysql-pluggins`, `mysql-community-client-core`, `mysql-common`, `mysql-community-client`.

Screenshot is shown below:
[image]

I had checked versions of MySQL and MySQL-server but it did not show anything and when I again installed it through its installation commands, it gave different dependency problems like `mssql-tools`, services etc. I am confused about how to solve the problem. Anyone to configure this issue because I had find anywhere this solution.

Comment: I have checked through first step-Cleaning, includes removing MySQL and SQL server because I had installed the SQL server only through apt and I want to connect through visual studio code extension MySQL by Microsoft or Jun Han, then completed the second step and aga in installing the third step (which is installation step) but again it gives error of dependency which is shows in next comment

Comment: (Removing msodbcsql17 (17.8.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--remove):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.)

Comment: it said that msobcsql17 post removal error, I had solved it through a lot of googling but did not configure it, I think multiple SQL servers I had installed because it is my first time to use sql server and MySQL in ubuntu and now it neither might be deleted completely and not installed completely????

Comment: I am unable to share a screenshot with you to show more errors while configuration of SQL server and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

not sure i understood exactly your problem. But i'm gonna take a shot.

## First Step - Cleaning

Since seems to be some stuff that don't agree to work togheter, uninstall everything and let's re-install with a clean environment. So...

### Notes

- Make sure to back up any important data from MySQL or SQL Server
  before going further
- The commands provided assume that you installed MySQL and SQL Server
  using the default package manager (apt). If you used a different
  method (such as downloading binaries directly) you might need to
  adapt those instructions accordingly.
- Always double-check commands before executing them to avoid unintended data loss

### Removing MySQL

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo deluser mysql
sudo delgroup mysql
```

### Removing SQL Server

```
sudo apt-get remove mssql-server
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/mssql /var/lib/mssql /etc/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.d
sudo deluser mssql
sudo delgroup mssql
```

## Second Step - Preparation

### SQL Server

I don't how did you precedently installed SQL Server, but if you used apt is almost sure that you already have done this.

```
$ sudo su
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
$ exit
```

### MySQL

Nothing to prepare. Is, as always, in the repo already

## Third Step - Installation

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server mysql-server
```

## Configuration

Is good practice to start playing with their configurations. Luckily, in both cases, you have 2 commands that will guide you throug every things and are pretty easy to use

### MySQL

sudo mysql_secure_installation
**Advice**: Follow the on-screen prompts to set a root password, remove anonymous users, disallow root login remotely, remove the test database, and reload the privilege tables

### SQL Server

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

Follow the prompts to set up the SA (System Administrator) password and choose the authentication method.

## Good to Know

- They are 2 databases made by differents people and that works on totally diferents ports. So, they can coexist on the same machine (but the real question here is WHY)
- All the tools you mentioned they do not create conflict with microsoft "ecosystem".
- next time you have dependeny conflict, put the logs togheter with your question

Comment: This is actually a pretty good answer, +1 from me. However, you may want to add few warnings. `/var/lib/mysql` will delete all databases installed on this server. I am pretty sure this will not be a problem for the OP, but it may destroy all the data of someone else who is reading this. Also `trusted.gpg` keyring is depicted, so using `apt-key add -` is not the best solution. This may be helpful for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1491498/1157209

Answer (score 0):

From you question it looks like you already installed MySQL. You can test if it works by doing: `sudo mysql`.

#### MySQL

The "various SQL server" (as you called them) that you are seeing in `dpkg -l | grep -i mysql` are packages related to your MySQL. You can read what they are used for in the last column.

For example: `mysql-client` is `MySQL database client binaries`. To simplify it, this installed the software that the command `mysql` uses.

#### SQL Server

It's not clear from you question what you want to do and what your problem here is. To me it looks like you want to install Microsoft's SQL Server. You can do this my following the official manual by Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2204

- Download Microsoft's certificate and sources list:

  ```
  curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
  curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2022.list
  ```
- Configure apt to use the correct certificate:

  This step is not in the official manual, but it was required in my case, because I was getting this error:

  > W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF

  Replace the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2022.list` with:

  ```
  deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy main
  ```
- Install the MS SQL Server:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install mssql-server
  ```

Comment: You can not understand my point, i had installed multiple version of MS SQL server , when I checked through  "dpkg -l | grep -i mysql" , it shows as I mentioned above whichmysql-community, mysql-common and others but when I run command "sudo systemctl status sqlserver.service", it gave me error "Unit sqlserver.service could not be found." and

Comment: when I execute "sudo mysql", it gives error "sudo: mysql: command not found" and when I execute " mysql -u root -h localhost -p", it gives again some strange error "Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.6  # version 1:10.6.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1" and

Comment: when want to delete all its packages, it says that package is not installed , so no removed and again did not access it as a root user, even it did not open SQL shell to create new user and set new password of user, nor it allow me to create again setup of SQL server. Mignt be now you had clarity with my question?

Comment: I again executed several commands to remove all the packages and dependencies od the SQL server like "sudo apt remove --purge mysql-apt-config mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core",

Comment: "sudo apt autoremove", "sudo apt remove --purge mysql-apt-config
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-client
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-common
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-client
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-client-core
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-client-plugins
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-server
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-community-server-core", all the commands in the terminal but did not removed the dependencies and packages related to MS SQL server, not it would be able  to create a client with new password.